# Dynamic column heading from user input

Tags: reporting-services

How can I use the user input for column heading in reporting service please?  My situation is

User will enter first (200901) and the second parameter (05).  I want to display the column heading like

200901 200902 200903 200904 200905

Thanks for all helps.

Comment: Is it for a finite number of columns? What data do you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

you must use matrix report control for this. in your query add a new column that reserve your month and use it in column data.

Comment: Can I have another question please?  How can you pass user inputs in the function in reporting service?  Ex: userinput1 is 01 and userinput2 is 04.  I like to pass into the function and calculate how many months from 01 to 04.
Thanks.